# How can I install a package in "developer mode" in R / RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am creating an R package, but I don't want to install and restart every time I make a change. Is there a way to install the package in developer mode, as in python, so that I can run the code that I modify?

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't already I would suggest installing the devtools package. The `load_all` function will load your package in it's current state.

Comment: that's very close to what I need. Is there a way to ensure I don't have to reissue it every time I start R, but it just becomes a link in the packrat environment I have?

Comment: Also, I noted that I have to invoke it again every time to see my changes. It doesn't automatically use the current code like in python. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

If you are building it inside RStudio, in a project, you can use `CTRL + Shift + L` to load the package so that you can test it interactively. [This link](https://hub.packtpub.com/how-to-create-your-own-r-package-with-rstudio-tutorial/) has some basic details around setting up a package in RStudio.